# GraphQL products query Access Denied

Tags: graphql, shopify

I'm a little stuck with one GraphQL query.

```
{
  collectionByHandle(handle:"price") {
    products(first: 16, sortKey:PRICE, query:"title:Bracelet"){
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error comes from the `query` parameter which is not supported on Custom collection, but it is on a Smart one.

> query: String
>
> This field is only used when the collection is smart. If the collection is custom it returns an error. Supported filter parameters:
>
> - title
> - product_type
> - vendor
> - gift_card
> - created_at
> - updated_at

So when I use a Custom collection I get the expected error result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "collectionByHandle": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot filter by query if the collection is a custom collection.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "collectionByHandle",
        "products"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I use a Smart collection I get `Access Denied`

```
{
  "data": {
    "collectionByHandle": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "access denied",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "collectionByHandle",
        "products"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The error message from the front-end is this:

> "Field 'products' doesn't accept argument 'query'"

So I don't see any reason why this request is not working properly if it is specified that the query parameter works only for Smart Collections and the collection is indeed setup as a smart one.

As to why I use `collectionByHandle` with `products` I need to sort the products by price and the products doesn't allow to be sorted by price if I don't include them in the collection.

Here is a video demo of the issue as well: https://streamable.com/sevtf

Any insight of the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean that "the products doesn't allow to be sorted by price"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're querying for the `products` connection under `queryroot`, you can use the `query` parameter:

```
{
    products(first: 16, sortKey:PRICE, query:"title:Bracelet"){
        edges {
            cursor
            node {
                title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, if you're in a `Collection` (as is the case in your code above), the `products` connection only has 6 supported parameters: `after`, `before`, `first`, `last`, `reverse`, and `sortKey` ***but not*** `query`.

The [Shopify help page](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/collection) gives more information on this.

Comment: But, What if I want to filter the products of the particular collection ? This only be done with `query`. Can you have solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong API endpoint.
I assumed you use the storeFront API, please try this: `/api/2019-10/graphql.json`

[Document](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference/object/productsortkeys)